# Designing correctly Java Classes

Tags: java, class, variables, object, private

Lets say I have the classes DrugAmount:

```
package core;

public abstract class DrugAmount {

    boolean drugInMg = false;
    boolean drugInMl = false;
    double numberofAmpoules = 0.0;
    double ampoulesInML = 0.0;
    double ampoulesInMG = 0.0;

    public DrugAmount() {
    }

    public DrugAmount(int numberOfAmpoules) {
        setNumberofAmpoules(numberOfAmpoules);
    }

    // SETTER:

    private void setNumberofAmpoules(int numberOfAmpoules) {
        this.numberofAmpoules = numberOfAmpoules;
    }

    // GETTER:

    public double getNumberOfAmpoules() {
        return numberofAmpoules;
    }

    public double getAmpoulesInML() {
        return ampoulesInML;
    }

    public double getAmpoulesInMG() {
        return ampoulesInMG;
    }

    public boolean isDrugInMl() {
        return drugInMl;
    }

    public boolean isDrugInMg() {
        return drugInMg;
    }

}
```

And the classes DrugAmountMg:

```
package core;

public class DrugAmountMg extends DrugAmount {

    public DrugAmountMg(double drugAmount) {
        super();
        setDrugInMg();
        setAmpoulesMG(drugAmount);
        setNumberOfAmpoules();
        turnDrugFromMgToMl();
    }

    public DrugAmountMg(int drugAmount) {
        super(drugAmount);
        setDrugInMg();
        setAmpoulesMG();
        turnDrugFromMgToMl();
    }

    private void setNumberOfAmpoules() {
        numberofAmpoules = ((1 / Ampoule.AMOUNT_OF_ONE_AMPOULE_IN_MG) * getAmpoulesInMG());
    }

    private void setAmpoulesMG() {
        ampoulesInMG=(Ampoule.AMOUNT_OF_ONE_AMPOULE_IN_MG*getNumberOfAmpoules());
    }

    private void setAmpoulesMG(double drugAmount) {
        ampoulesInMG=drugAmount;
    }

    private void turnDrugFromMgToMl() {
        if (isDrugInMg()) {
            ampoulesInML=(Ampoule.AMOUNT_OF_ONE_AMPOULE_IN_ML / Ampoule.AMOUNT_OF_ONE_AMPOULE_IN_MG) * getAmpoulesInMG();
        }
    }

    private void setDrugInMg() {
        drugInMg = true;
    }
}
```

Like you can see there are "package private" object variables in the class DrugAmount - is this good java practice?

Or should I modify them to private and declare new object variables in the child class DrugAmountMg and assign them the value of the DrugAmount-variables by getter-methods?

Comment: This is opinion-based. Do what is easier to read/manage for YOU. If you want opinions on how you should improve already working code, check out [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). This site is for specific programming *problems*

Comment: Would be much better posting on the Code Review Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leave them as they are, but will you really ever need to access them from other classes in the same package that are not subclasses? I would make them `protected` in the base class.

You should definitely *not* declare new fields in the child class. The class would then have two of each field (say, `drugInMg` for instance), and even though only one of them would be in scope in the source code of the child class, you could run into trouble if you were to try to set the private field through reflection, for example in a unit test. On the project I'm working on we have occasionally run into problems with that, where a class has fields with the same type and name declared as private fields at different points in the class hierarchy, and unit tests that use a reflective utility to set up the private field fail because they've set the wrong one.

I'm not sure what you mean by "assign them the value of the DrugAmount-variables by getter-methods". I suspect you meant that you would make the fields private in the base class, create getters, duplicate the fields in the child class, and get the value from the base class to set up the child? Again, duplicating fields in this way is a bad idea.

The other thing you could do is make the fields private in the base class and provide getters *and setters* to allow the child classes to update the fields, but that creates the potential for outsiders to call the setters. You could make the setters protected or package-private, but why not just make the actual fields protected? Then only subclasses can access them.

Comment: Yes you described my "problem" correctly! Thanks for the answer!